# S3 cloudfront expiry on images - performance very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I recently started serving my website images on cloudfront CDN instead of S3 thinking that it would be much faster. It is not. In fact it is much much slower. After a lot of investigation I'm being hinted that setting an expiry date on image objects is the key as Cloudfront will know how long to keep cached static content. Makes sense. But this is poorly documented by AWS and I can't figure out how to change the expiry date. people have said "you can change this on the aws console" Please show how dumb I am because I cannot see this. been at it for several hours. Needless to say I'm quite frustrated of fumbling around on this. Anyways any hints as small as they might be would be terrific. I like AWS, and what Cloudfront promised, but so far it's not what it seems.

EDIT ADITIONAL DETAIL:
Added expiry date headers per answer. In my case I had no headers. My hypothesis was that my slow Cloudfront performance serving images had to do with having NO expiry in the header. Having set an expiry date as shown in screenshot, and described in the answer, I'm seeing no noticeable difference in performance (going from no headers to adding an expiry date only). My site takes on average 7s to load with 10 core images (each <60Kbs). Those 10 images (served via cloudfront) account for 60-80% of the load time latency - depending on the performance tool used. Obviously something is wrong given that serving files on my VPS is faster. I hate to conclude that cloudfront is the problem given that so many people use it and I'd hate to break of from EC2 and S3, but right now testing MAxCDN is showing better results. I'll keep testing over the next 24hrs, but my conclusion is that the expiry date header is just a confusing detail with no favorable impact. Hopefully I'm wrong because I'd like to keep it all in the AWS family. Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree on the expiry date thing?

Comment: I am seeing worse performance with CloudFront as well - one year later...  Did you ever get a resolution or did you just switch to MaxCDN?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set it in the meta-data while uploading the file into S3. [This article](http://www.cloudcomputingetc.com/2011/07/how-to-add-expires-headers-to-images.html) describes how you can achieve this.

The format for the expiry date is the RFC1123 date which is formatted like this:

```
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
```

Setting this to a far future date will enable caches like CloudFront to hold the file for a long time and in this case speed up the delivery as the single edge-locations (server all over the world delivering content for CloudFront) already have the data and don't need to fetch it again and again.

Even with a far future expiry header the first request of an object will be slow as the edge-location has to fetch the object once before it can be served from the cache.

**Alternately** you can omit the `Expires` header and use `Cache-Control` instead. CloudFront will understand that one too and you are more flexible with the expiry. In that case you can for example state the object should be held for one day from the first request the edge-location made to the object:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
```

In that case the time is given using seconds instead of a fixed date.

Comment: This article is not at all helpful.

Comment: Ok, so is expiring the object going to improve performance? What is an optimal time? How should I format the date?  These are static images on a website served by cloudfront.

Comment: If you are really sure you **never** will change the image again you can set the expiry time to 2100 or even later.

An example for the date is this: `Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT`

Comment: I was hopeful with that article, but no dice. I entered the value/date that you want the image to be expired from caching (ie. Fri, Apr 23 2021 10:18:36 GMT). In fact I used the same date per example.
Then clicked SAVE.  NOTHING 
See screenshot http://screencast.com/t/ce8f7w3a

Comment: Geez, and what if it does change? My website loads imagaes like 1999 on Cloudfront. Am I doing the right thing here? And why is it NOT showing an expiry date after I click save?  Thank you. But this is super frustrating.

Comment: I've added more details on dynamic expiration dates and how this works to my answer as there is more space for explanations. The _Expiration Rule_ you showed in your screenshot has nothing to do with the expiration header. It is about when to automatically remove an object from the S3 bucket. So in your case the object will not get removed from the bucket.

The only way to see the expiration header itself in action is to make a request to the object and for example watch your browsers network inspector…

Comment: It sounded like from your answer that I should be good then? Your last sentence threw me:  "The only way to see the expiration header itself in action is to make a request to the object and for example watch your browsers network inspector." I'm very confused now. So do I need to do something else not explain in your detailed answer above.

Comment: No. If you set those values you're fine and you should see an increase in performance. That was only a technical detail how you could check whether the header was added to the headers but not a required step.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'm now wondering if I should invalidate each and every object on my cloudfront distribution after setting up the expiry. Thoughts?

Comment: You don't have to but you can do it. They will expire after their previous expiry time and then get your new expiry headers.

Comment: No performance improvement. I added expiry dates to all 10 core images. S3 seems slightly better at performance. I think I'm barking up the wrong tree with the expiry date header ya yas. Something else is wrong. I'll research a bit more and provide a final synopsis later. Moving to MaxCDN is unfortunately a chore given that I'm already in bed with EC2/S3 - which I love. Quite disappointed with Cloudfront. Hopefully I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

While setting Cache-Control or Expires headers will improve the cache-ability of your objects, it won't improve your 60k/sec download speed. This requires some help from AWS.  Therefore, I would recommend posting to the [AWS CloudFront Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=46) with some sample response headers, traceroutes and resolver information.